# Подскажите как сверстать блок с данного изображения

Tags: html

Не могу придумать, как сверстать данный блок.
!(https://ibb.co/P9L01HC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А все на самом деле очень просто, добавляете div (это наша заготовка) у него помещаете картинку (размер и позицию делайте в процентах). Потом в этот же div добавлять текст отсекая абзацы линиями (<.hr>) и размещаем наш div. Вот и всё. Если останутся вопросы, пишите. Хорошего дня!